# Error: Dependency "python3" not found

Tags: python, dependencies, compiling, python3, compiler

I am somewhat new to Linux and have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS two weeks ago.
I was following a process today which had me download Meson and Ninja to compile something.  I'd run the compiler, it would mention a dependency, which I would install and repeat the process.  Once all dependencies were met, I was told:
`meson.build:554:0: ERROR:  Dependency "python3" not found`

running `which python3` outputs `/usr/bin/python3` and I haven't modified it in any way.

Does anyone know what's going on?  I don't have very much installed yet, but it is worth noting that I tried to build the same Meson package on my first Ubuntu attempt (have reformatted since) and got past this step.

Last time, I was not aware that python3 shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 and attempted to install it anyway.  For the sake of learning Linux / Python properly I am reticent to attempt that before someone tells me to do it again!

Comment: I am trying to compile libratbag for Logitech hardware.  You may be right?  It also depends on libudev-dev, libevdev-dev, and libglib-2.0-dev.  I should point out that I don't have an understanding of compilers.  Thanks for your advice so far.

Comment: Update: yes, python3-dev had everything I needed.  Thanks @dsstorefile1